# prometheus field remote_write not found in type config.plain

Tags: prometheus

I need help using prometheus remote_write and remote_read to/from influxdb.
I got error below:

```
# promtool check config /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
Checking /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
  FAILED: parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 5: field remote_write not found in type config.plain
  line 7: field remote_read not found in type config.plain
```

Here is my prometheus.yml

```
# head /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
---
global:
  scrape_interval: 60s
  evaluation_interval: 60s
  remote_write:
      - url: "http://192.168.0.10:8086/api/v1/prom/write?db=promtestdb&u=myuser&p=mypassword"
  remote_read:
      - url: "http://192.168.0.10:8086/api/v1/prom/read?db=promtestdb&u=myuser&p=mypassword"
scrape_configs:
- job_name: ldr
```

Answer (score 1):

my bad, editing prometheus.yml as below resolved the issue!

```
# head /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
---
global:
  scrape_interval: 60s
  evaluation_interval: 60s
remote_write:
      - url: "http://192.168.0.10:8086/api/v1/prom/write?db=promtestdb&u=myuser&p=mypassword"
remote_read:
      - url: "http://192.168.0.10:8086/api/v1/prom/read?db=promtestdb&u=myuser&p=mypassword"
scrape_configs:
- job_name: ldr
```

Comment: I've just made the same mistake. Your answer helps me to got it)